# How to Compute RGB Image Standard Deviation from per Channel values

Tags: opencv, image-processing, statistics, standard-deviation

Is there any way how one can compute RGB image standard deviation from the channel values?

What I mean is: I have standard deviation values for each channel - this is easily calculated with [cv::meanStdDev()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga846c858f4004d59493d7c6a4354b301d) function. What I'd like is to have one single stddev value of the whole image.

Comment: The standard deviation tells you the deviation from the samples to the mean.... squared then averaged and then root squared (look at the [formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)) so basically you can add the calculation of each deviation (using the mean from each channel respectively) and use an average it with the sum of the 3 channels amount of pixels. then get the square root and you get the value :)

Comment: I literally dont know what you mean -- or at least I'm very confused by your thinking. I am of course familiar with the formula, but I dont understand your thinking. We have dev_R, dev_G, dev_B, where each dev_chan_j = sqrt(sum(pixel_i_chan_j * mean_chan_j)/N) - pixel_i_chan_j is a pixel from particular channel j - pixel_i in channel R != pixel_i in channel G or B. I want dev_pixel_across_all_channels